# Add another measure in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

**MDX Query:**

```
SELECT NON EMPTY
{ [Time].[Date].[Date].AllMembers } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
{ [Person].[Alias].[Alias].AllMembers } ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
WHERE ( [Measures].[Count Person] )
```

**Result Format:**

```
        2014-04-01  2014-04-02  2014-04-04  

XYZ     14          36          68
```

What if I want to include another measure [Measures].[Person%] as a column and get result in following format:

```
        Person% 2014-04-01  2014-04-02  2014-04-04  

XYZ     10%         14          36          68
```

How can I arrange query?

Comment: For which time do you want to show the measure `Person%`?

Comment: @FrankPl for each Person I want the result. There is no condition on Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT NON EMPTY
{ ( [Measures].[Person%], [Time].[Date].[All]) }
+
{[Measures].[Count Person]} * [Time].[Date].[Date].AllMembers
ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
{ [Person].[Alias].[Alias].AllMembers } ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

just using two hierarchies (measures and time) in the columns.